# How to exclude doubled DOMDocument elements

Tags: php, domdocument

I have trying to pull titles from a page. Everything seems to work so far but I've got doubled results. For example I'm getting `h3` titles. On the page is one time but in the source is 2 times.

Here is the example

```
<span data-img-type='cvr' data-img-att-alt='Cover of Greek Mythology' data-img-size-xs='image.jpg'></span>
<h3> Cover of Greek Mythology </h3>
```

This will return

```
Cover of Greek Mythology
Cover of Greek Mythology
```

I'm targeting only h3 elements but they still appear doubled. How can I remove repeated elements?

Here is what I have so far

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://example.com/'); 

$scriptDocument = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); 

if(!empty($html)){ 

    $scriptDocument->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); 
    $scriptDOMXPath = new DOMXPath($scriptDocument);
    //get all the h3's with an class
    $scriptRow = $scriptDOMXPath->query('//h3[@class]');
    //check
    if($scriptRow->length > 0){
        foreach($scriptRow as $row){
            echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `//h3[@class]` in xpath select h3 element has class attribute that in your example doesn't exist. When i used `//h3` in xpath it return only one text not doubled. Check https://3v4l.org/brmut

Comment: Hi, I've forget to add `class` to the `<h3>`. I was removed it while I tested few options and copied it here without the class. Yes, your demo doesn't show doubled titles which is strange.